# How to achieve shake animation programmatically?

Tags: android

How can I achieve shake/wobble animation in android programmatically.
There is a [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations) library available through which we can get the effect.
But I don't want to use any library for this purpose as it tends to increase the apk size.

The code present in the [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations) for shake animation is as follows:

```
public class ShakeAnimator extends BaseViewAnimator {
    @Override
    public void prepare(View target) {
        getAnimatorAgent().playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationX", 0, 25, -25, 25, -25,15, -15, 6, -6, 0)
        );
    }
}
```

Can annyone tell me how can I achieve this without any libraries.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

let's say that `mView` is the view you want to animate:

```
ObjectAnimator
  .ofFloat(mView, "translationX", 0, 25, -25, 25, -25,15, -15, 6, -6, 0)
  .setDuration(duration)
  .start();
```

Comment: what are the value ? how i can modify ? like adding more shake

Comment: It is working, thanks, but please explain the each values

Answer (score 5):

Just to provide another possible answer to the question. The below animation file need to be put under **res/anim** folder :

shake.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-2%p" /> <!-- -2 -->

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="66"
        android:toXDelta="4%p" /> <!-- 2 -->

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="132"
        android:toXDelta="-4%p" /> <!-- -2 -->

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="198"
        android:toXDelta="4%p" /> <!-- 2 -->

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="264"
        android:toXDelta="-3%p" /> <!-- -1 -->

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="330"
        android:toXDelta="2%p" /> <!-- 1 -->

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="396"
        android:toXDelta="-1.5%p" /> <!-- -0.5 -->

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="462"
        android:toXDelta="1%p" /> <!-- 0.5 -->

    <translate
        android:duration="66"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="528"
        android:toXDelta="-0.5%p" /> <!-- 0 -->

</set>
```

And to use it in code (Here in Kotlin) :

```
val animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), R.anim.shake)
mView.startAnimation(animShake)
```

Animation explanation:

- If you want 1000ms of duration, you need to divide this by the number of step in your anim.
  Ex. with 5 steps: 1000/5 = 200
  So if you put 200 of duration for each step, all will take same time to end
- The "startOffset" parameter need to specify after what time the animation need to start (Here we wanted to sum all of before operations)
- The "fromXDelta" parameter is your started point at each step, based on the previous step.