# Make an ImageView shake using only Java

Tags: java, android, xml, image, imageview

I need to make an `ImageView` shake `onClick` using only java. I have looked at a couple other similar questions, but those are mainly `XML`. I a need it only using java.

Comment: because, as docs prefers use xml animation for code re-usability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's say that `mView` is the view you want to animate:

```
ObjectAnimator
  .ofFloat(mView, "translationX", 0, 25, -25, 25, -25,15, -15, 6, -6, 0)
  .setDuration(duration)
  .start();
```

answer credits [Budius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943288/5235032)